# Problem calling functions within case and if loop

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm new to bash scripting and in this file I'm trying to clean up my code. The first one works perfectly. In the second one, I simply group the code into two functions and call them within the case and if loop, but after testing the second does not work at all. Can anyone tell me where I did wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

#check is the file exists
if [ ! -e $HOME/recyclebin/$1 ]; then
   echo "$0: Cannot restore \`$1': No such file or directory"
   exit 8
fi

#check if the filename is provided
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
   echo "$0: missing operand"
   exit 9
fi

#get the original name and path of file being restored
tempname=$(grep $1 $HOME/.restore.info|cut -d ":" -f1)
temppath=$(grep $1 $HOME/.restore.info|cut -d":" -f2)

#get the dirname of temppath
dirpath=$(dirname $temppath)

#check if the file being restored already exists in the target directory
if [ -e $temppath ]; then
   read -p "Do you want to overwrite? y/n " opt
   case $opt in
      [yY]|yes)
              mv $HOME/recyclebin/$1 $temppath
              grep -v $1 $HOME/.restore.info > $HOME/project/restore.temp
              mv $HOME/project/restore.temp $HOME/.restore.info;;
      *) echo "Restored failed because file already exists";;
   esac
else
   mkdir -p $dirpath
   mv $HOME/recyclebin/$1 $temppath
   grep -v $1 $HOME/.restore.info > $HOME/restore.temp
   mv $HOME/restore.temp $HOME/.restore.info
fi
```

###################starting of the second #########################

```
#!/bin/bash

#check is the file exists
if [ ! -e $HOME/recyclebin/$1 ]; then
   echo "$0: Cannot restore \`$1': No such file or directory"
   exit 8
fi

#check if the filename is provided
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
   echo "$0: missing operand"
   exit 9
fi

#get the original name and path of file being restored
tempname=$(grep $1 $HOME/.restore.info|cut -d ":" -f1)
temppath=$(grep $1 $HOME/.restore.info|cut -d":" -f2)

#get the dirname of temppath
dirpath=$(dirname $temppath)

function overwrite() {
   mv $HOME/recyclebin/$1 $temppath
   grep -v $1 $HOME/.restore.info > $HOME/project/restore.temp
   mv $HOME/project/restore.temp $HOME/.restore.info
}

function resotreDir() {
   mkdir -p $dirpath
   mv $HOME/recyclebin/$1 $temppath
   grep -v $1 $HOME/.restore.info > $HOME/restore.temp
   mv $HOME/restore.temp $HOME/.restore.info
}

#check if the file being restored already exists in the target directory
if [ -e $temppath ]; then
   read -p "Do you want to overwrite? y/n " opt
   case $opt in
      [yY]|yes)
              $(overwrite);;
      *) echo "Restored failed because file already exists";;
   esac
else
   $(restoreDir)
fi
```

Comment: looks like your overwrite function is expecting at least one parameter ($1) and you're not providing that at the point of a call.

Comment: `$(overwrite);;` You want to execute the output of a function? Just `overwrite <filename>; ;;`

Comment: Not relevant, but neither `case` nor `if` is a loop. They are just compound statements. `while` and `for` are loops.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you, it works now, was missing the ; after the filename and gave me weird errors

Comment: Paste your code into https://shellcheck.net -- there are several issues to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Per @vgersh99, `overwrite()` and `restoreDir()` make use of the `$1` variable which refers to each function's first argument. You could back the top-level `$1` variable up to a global like `FILE_LOCATION` and reference that, or simply pass it to your functions as needed:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#check is the file exists
if [ ! -e $HOME/recyclebin/$1 ]; then
   echo "$0: Cannot restore \`$1': No such file or directory"
   exit 8
fi

#check if the filename is provided
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
   echo "$0: missing operand"
   exit 9
fi

#get the original name and path of file being restored
tempname=$(grep $1 $HOME/.restore.info|cut -d ":" -f1)
temppath=$(grep $1 $HOME/.restore.info|cut -d":" -f2)

#get the dirname of temppath
dirpath=$(dirname $temppath)

function overwrite() {
   mv $HOME/recyclebin/$1 $temppath
   grep -v $1 $HOME/.restore.info > $HOME/project/restore.temp
   mv $HOME/project/restore.temp $HOME/.restore.info
}

function restoreDir() {
   mkdir -p $dirpath
   mv $HOME/recyclebin/$1 $temppath
   grep -v $1 $HOME/.restore.info > $HOME/restore.temp
   mv $HOME/restore.temp $HOME/.restore.info
}

# CALL WITH ARGUMENT
#check if the file being restored already exists in the target directory
if [ -e $temppath ]; then
   read -p "Do you want to overwrite? y/n " opt
   case $opt in
      [yY]|yes)
              overwrite "$1";;
      *) echo "Restored failed because file already exists";;
   esac
else
   restoreDir "$1";
fi
```

Comment: `overwrite $1;` -> `overwrite "$1";;`